# Beta reduction of some lambda

Tags: lambda, lambda-calculus

I have following lambda calculus and want to know to beta reduction of it.

The lambda is:

```
λxy.xy
```

I suppose, that it can't do beta reduce because there is no substitution and the x is bound to the body.

Is my assumption right?

Comment: Yes. You can only eta reduce here.

Comment: what is eta reduce?

Comment: Looks like it is more commonly known as [eta _conversion_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion)

Comment: Is the x an expression? How can I descript x ?

Comment: Sometimes in lambda-calculus you work only with the beta rule, sometimes you add the eta reduction rule as well. If you only care about beta, your term is already as reduced as possible -- it is in beta-normal form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot apply beta-reduction (which is probably what you are looking for). Beta-reduction can only be applied on function applications (and even then not in all cases).

You *can* apply eta conversion, which transforms λx.fx to f when x does not appear freely in f. Then you can convert your expression:

λxy.xy = λx.λy.xy →<sub>η</sub> λx.x (= I).

Comment: sorry I can't follow you. What does eta conversion mean? Can you please show me an very simple example? What does (= I) mean?

Comment: @zero_coding Eta conversion means simply that if some abstraction only applies a constant expression f to its argument x (i.e. `\x.fx`, if f does not contain x) then that abstraction is equivalent to f itself. The abstraction only boxes f / forwards x, so it can be removed.